# c# load inherited class from external dll in runtime

Tags: c#, dll, runtime, .net-assembly

atm Im "playing" a bit with the things C# can do - just to know how it works.
Now I had the idea to load a class from a dll in runtime that extends a class from my original program. Example:

```
// My class in the dll.
namespace MyDll
{
  public class MyClassInDll : MyClass
  {
    public MyClassInDll(int num) : base(num)
    {
      // May contain more code :)
    }
  }
}

// My abstract class which is inherited in the dll.
namespace MyProgram
{  
  public class MyClass
  {
    private int num;

    public MyClass(int numToUse)
    {
      num = numToUse;
    }

    public void WriteTheNumber()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
  }
}

// My mainfile.
namespace MyProgram
{  
  public class Program
  {
    public void Main(String[] args)
    {
      // Load the DLL
      Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFile("myDll.dll");

      // Create an instance of MyClassInDll stored as MyClass.
      MyClass myclass = ? // I dont know what to enter here :(

      // Call the function my program knows from MyClass
      myclass.WriteTheNumber(); // this should write the in the constructor passed integer to the console.
    }
  }
}
```

So here are my questions:

- Most important: what do I need to do there to create an instance? (The constructor needs a parameter to be passed)
- How can I check if it was successfull (or better which exceptions means what?)
- What (else) could go wrong (dll not found, dll doesnt contain the class, class in dll doesnt extend MyClass, MyClassInDll has a different constructor than assumed, MyClass has different methods and attributes than version of the MyClass that was used in the dll) and is there anyting I can do?
- Do methodcalls use a eventually overriden method in the dll? (sould but Im not sure)

I realy hope you can help me with this, all I found on Google was about running a single method in a class in an external dll (or I was too stupid to see the answer) but found nothing about inherited classes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the way you defined `MyClass` is not abstract, if you need it to be an abstract class then you need to add the abstract modifier keyword, with this in mind i will continue the answer as if `MyClass` is a concrete class

> Most important: what do I need to do there to create an instance? (The constructor needs a parameter to be passed)

Yes, the constructor of MyClass needs a parameter, and integer to be precise, so you would need to write something like this:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass(1);
```

> How can I check if it was successfull (or better which exceptions
>   means what?)

If you are saying from loading the dll, I can tell you there is a much better way to add a dll to your project, add it as a reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019

> What (else) could go wrong (dll not found, dll doesnt contain the
>   class, class in dll doesnt extend MyClass, MyClassInDll has a
>   different constructor than assumed, MyClass has different methods and
>   attributes than version of the MyClass that was used in the dll) and
>   is there anyting I can do?

You cant have two MyClass with different methods and attributes you should only have one and consume that one from both projects (your dll and your main method).

> Do methodcalls use a eventually overriden method in the dll? (sould
>   but Im not sure)

You can only override methods if you mark a method as virtual, but I think this question is because you are using 2 MyClass classes which as I said before is a mistake.

I hope with this, im being clear enough but if you need further help please leave a comment.

Comment: 1)I want to load it dynamicly because I want to test somethink like the pluginsystem from Minecraft where you just place the .jar in the plugins folder and writes in a file what class extends the JavaPlugin class. On startup the game just finds the jar and loads the class in it.
2) I know I can use MyClass myclass = new MyClass(1); but I want MyClass myclas = new MyClassInDll(1); :)
3) I mean the MyClass which was used to compile the dll is for example older and have diferent methods or with different parameter.

Comment: And yes I know that I can only override virtual methods but I mean what if I had a method I could override :)

Comment: 1) Then you should load it in a try catch block, you should seek for the error on mdsn for the LoadFile method. 2) You should review this webpage on how to use dynamically dll with reflection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly?view=netframework-4.8 3) As i said you should only have 1 MyClass, and it has to be updated in that place so you dont have this kind of problems. 4) if you mark a method as virtual and you make a class inheriting from that class you will be able to override those methods.

Comment: So I tried a bit and it works but only without arguments in the constructor. How do I pass arguments to the constructor? I found this: CreateInstance(String, Boolean, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo, Object[]) but i have no idea about Binder, BindingFlags or activationAttributes so i have no idea how to use this method. could you give me an example for the "normal" use? Like `CreateInstance("MyDll.MyClassInDll", true, ?, ?, myArgsAsObjectArray, null, ?);`?
Thats the last thing I need to make this work.

Comment: You can pass null to all those things, the binder and attribute binder are to specify on how do you want to perform the search of the method due to using reflection, and the last attribute im not sure what is used for but im seeing that it should not be used in new implementations so try nulling that too

Comment: I cant set the BinderFlags to null. I get the error that <NULL> cant be convertet to BindingFlags. But BindingBlags.Default worked. Thank you realy much for your help!